# Kendo UI Mobile listview datasource not working

Tags: user-interface, listview, kendo-ui, datasource

I am trying to bind a field returned from a web service to a listview.

The Json object is:

> {"retrieveIndividualAccountResponse":
>   {"operationResult":"SUCCESS","responseDateTime":"2015-07-15T00:53:43.464+0000","individualAccount":{"createdDateTime":"2012-04-30T05:00:00.000+0000","lastModifiedDateTime":"2013-06-26T05:00:00.000+0000","accountId":3280,"primaryContact":{"contactId":3280,"firstName":"Mike","lastName":"Barber","preferredName":"Mike","phone1":"817
>   360-7057","phone1Type":"MOBILE","phone2":"817
>   334-7360","phone2Type":"WORK","fax":"817
>   334-7364","email1":"michael.barber@capitalone.com","email2":"","email3":"","deceased":false,"addresses":{"address":[{"addressId":3521,"isPrimaryAddress":true,"isShippingAddress":false,"addressType":{"id":"1","name":"Home"},"addressLine1":"505
>   Main Street, Suite 300","city":"Fort
>   Worth","state":{"code":"TX","name":"TEXAS"},"country":{"id":"1","name":"United
>   States"},"zipCode":"76102"},{"addressId":4163,"isPrimaryAddress":false,"isShippingAddress":false,"addressType":{"id":"2","name":"Business"}}]},"title":"Fort
>   Worth Area
>   President"},"noSolicitation":false,"customFieldDataList":{"customFieldData":[]},"source":{},"existingOrganizationId":3917,"individualTypes":
>   {"individualType":[{"id":"32","name":"LC Prospect 2017"}]}}}}

The html view is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Datasource</title>
    </head>
    <body>               
       <div data-role="view" id="memberProfileView" data-title="Member Profile" data-show="showMemberProfile">
           <h3>Edit Profile</h3> 
           <ul id="memberProfileUL"
                data-source="memberProfileData"
                data-endlessScroll="true"
                data-template="memberProfileTemplate"
                data-role="listview"
                data-style="inset">
            </ul>
       </div>
       <script id="memberProfileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <li>
                <h3>#: FirstName#</h3>  
            </li>
       </script> 

       <script>

          var MemberProfile = kendo.data.Model.define({
              id: "retrieveIndividualAccountResponse.individualAccount.primaryContact.accountId",
              fields: {
                FirstName: "retrieveIndividualAccountResponse.individualAccount.primaryContact.firstName"
              }
          })

          var memberProfileData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read:  {                        
                        url: "https://api.neoncrm.com/neonws/services/api/account/retrieveIndividualAccount?responseType=json&userSessionId=cf96ec15f21d271366c2d03b8bff1a83&accountId=3280",
                        dataType: "jsonp"                           
                    },
                    schema: {
                    model: MemberProfile
                    }
                }
            });           

        function showMemberProfile(e){
                //accountID = e.view.params.accountID;
                //sessID = e.view.params.userSess;
                memberProfileData.fetch();
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to run it in the Telerik simulator, it just displayed 'Loading...'.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the 'data' configuration in your datasource. It should be like this:

```
var memberProfileData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:  {                        
                    url: "https://api.neoncrm.com/neonws/services/api/account/retrieveIndividualAccount?responseType=json&userSessionId=cf96ec15f21d271366c2d03b8bff1a83&accountId=3280",
                    dataType: "jsonp"                           
                },
                schema: {
                model: MemberProfile
                },
                data: "retrieveIndividualAccountResponse.individualAccount.primaryContact"
            }
        });
```

if it doesnt work please send jsfiddle link or something similar.

Comment: Hi Akis_Tfs, 
Thanks for your reply. I changed the code as you suggested and got the same result. I am not familiar with jsfiddle and will
try to figure out how to use it.   
I changed the url in the datasource to point to a local file 'members.json' which contains the json data included in my original
post. But, the result was same. the page stayed in 'Loading' phase forever.
Here is the updated lines. other lines remain the same.